# How to create custom view of markers in google maps in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

[How to show custom view markers in Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsu9h.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An Image is not an acceptable question, please provide additional details about your problem and what you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker) on how to add markers.

Specifically, these few lines:

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10, longitude: 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .black) // or any image here
marker.map = mapView
```